# MySql метка времени с микросекундами?

Tags: mysql

Как установить метку времени с микросекундами значением по умолчанию?

Comment: @zenith, Вы верите в правильность микросекунд в современных ОС?

Comment: @avp на самом деле необходимость в микросекундах в бд уже отпала, после правки кода, но вопрос сам по себе интересный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вообщето судя по ченджлогу версии 5.6.4 можно...
[баг старый и известный](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=8523)

> Noted in 5.6.4 changelog.
>
> MySQL now supports fractional seconds
> for TIME, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP
> values, with up to microsecond
> precision.

Comment: [пруф](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/news-5-6-4.html)

Answer (score 1):

Никак. MySQL не поддерживает хранение микросекунд. Но можете создать свой формат даты-времени.